# Load DDS textures with Three.js SceneLoader

Tags: three.js

I'm having issues trying to load dds textures with SceneLoader.
I'm currently using version 69 of three.js. I have tried modifying the SceneLoader to use THREE.DDSLoader but my page stalls and produce no errors.

Modification:
                var isCompressed = fullUrl.toLowerCase().endsWith(".dds"); // had to add prototype endsWith
                //console.warn(isCompressed);

```
            if ( isCompressed) {
                var loader = new THREE.DDSLoader();
                console.log(fullUrl);
                var texture = loader.load(fullUrl);         
            }
            else{

               var loader = THREE.Loader.Handlers.get( fullUrl );

               if ( loader !== null ) {

                   texture = loader.load( fullUrl, textureCallback );

               } else {

                   texture = new THREE.Texture();
                   loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

                   ( function ( texture ) {

                       loader.load( fullUrl, function ( image ) {

                           texture.image = image;
                           texture.needsUpdate = true;

                           textureCallback();

                       } );

                   } )( texture )


               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out.
I needed to replace var texture = loader.load(fullUrl) with texture = loader.load( fullUrl, textureCallback );